# Avoid blinking when launching a .cmd file

Tags: cmd, executable

I was downgraded from Vista to XP for reasons that are not relevant.

I found very useful the snipping tool which is not available in XP so I decided to create my own.

[alt text http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/8851/snip251609121640.png](http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/8851/snip251609121640.png)

It works just fine so I put it int .cmd file for easy launching ( I didn't feel like creating the .jar file )

My only problem now is the command prompt screen pops up and disappear giving an unpleasant effect.

This is it:

```
echo off
start javaw -classpath lib\myutil.jar;classes recortes.Main
```

Is there a way the command just run without blinking ? ( other than creating the .jar file? )

**EDIT**

I have followed the advice of Jeffrey. I had a shorcut to the .cmd file, now the shortcut it self has the following:

```
 "C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -classpath lib\myutil.jar;classes -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties  recortes.Main
```

Start in:

```
 C:\Users\oreyes\recortes
```

And works just fine!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut (.lnk) file which contains the path to the executable with arguments.  [See KB244677](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244677) for information on how to do this from a script.

Comment: I have a shortcut to the .cmd file. Do you mean I should put the content of the .cmd directly in the shortcut?

Comment: It works fine ( well almost be cause the program fails :P ) Where is the stdout now? :)

Comment: Oh.. I guess I have to use java.util.logging.